# Protractor test broke after enabling local SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, protractor

My Protractor and Typescript based test code is broken, after team install local SSL certificate on the server. Though it able to load the provided URL on browser but still throwing error " **Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application.**"

Based on [Protractor-invalid-ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770336/protractor-invalid-ssl-certificate) link have added below snippet in my config but still it throw same error. Have also tried with other options: 
acceptSslCerts: true, trustAllSSLCertificates: true, acceptInsecureCerts:true,
ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS:true

But none of the option/arguments work.

```
/**Browser capabilities  */
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    marionette : true,
    acceptInsecureCerts : true
 },
```

Have also tried with firefox still getting same error.

Using Node v8.11.3, chrome 69.0, Protractor 5.4.0, Jasmine 2

Comment: Based on the error, when I add browser.ignoreSynchronization=true before my url load. Then code works and able to identify the elements. and able to perform the action however consistency of execution result is issue.

Answer (score 2):

When using browser 'chrome', do not set marionette propertie its firefox specific.

You can try with the following capability for chrome:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    trustAllSSLCertificates: true,
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS: true,
 },
```

Comment: Do you see the ssl certificate error page when website is open?

Comment: yes, but after using --ignore_ssl  with webdriver-manager update it does not come

Comment: It doesn't work and again the authentication is not disabled